# Redmine Invalid command RailsBaseURI to restart apache2

Tags: apache, ubuntu, redmine

**Subject:** http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_25x_on_Ubuntu_1404_with_Apache2_Phusion_Passenger_MySQL_and_Subversion

```
$service apache2 restart
```

**Output:**
Syntax error on line 10 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/redmine:
Invalid command 'RailsBaseURI', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module
not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!

**file /etc/apache2/sites-available/redmine:**

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        ServerName myservername

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule   ^/$  /redmine  [R]

    <Directory /var/www/redmine>
            RailsBaseURI /redmine
            PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
```

Information:

```
redmine 3.0
rvm 1.6.9
ruby 1.9.3p0
Apache/2.2.22 
Phusion Passenger version 4.0.59
```

Apache is not recognizing the passenger commands, right?
It will be a problem with the mod_passenger.so?
Suggestions?

Comment: So, what are you asking?  It's not considered within the guidelines of SO to ask us to debug your code.

Comment: I want help to find the cause of this error

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming issue.  Or am I missing something?  I wonder if it would be better for you to post this question on **Server Fault**, another of the StackExchange forums.